# Accessing Swift Class Public Variable in Objective-C Class Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, variables, xcode9

I am trying to access Public variable in Objective-C class declared in swift class. But I am getting "Unknown Method" error. Here is my code for accessing variable:

```
NSLog(@"job on quick blox : %@",[QuickBloxJobClass jobOnQB]);
```

and it shows compile error:

> No known class method for selector 'jobOnQB'

And here is my code in QuickBloxJobClass:

```
@objc public class QuickBloxJobClass: NSObject
{
    static var jobOnQB: QBCOCustomObject = QBCOCustomObject ()
}
```

I cannot make it public variable because I have Class methods in `QuickBloxJobClass`. Even I tried it by creating a variable for `QuickBloxJobClass`. But the variable was still unaccessible. 
It was working working fine in Xcode .

Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why `jobOnQB` cannot be public, presence of `class` methods should not interfere with it being public, but if it cannot be public for some reason, you can add a static method to `QuickBloxJobClass` to get the variable.

BTW, the syntax `[QuickBloxJobClass jobOnQB]` is for calling a static method `jobOnQB` on class `QuickBloxJobClass` (it works, though).  Strictly speaking, however, since `jobOnQB` is a property, a better Objective-C syntax would be `QuickBloxJobClass.jobOnQB`.

Another observation is that `@objc` inference is deprecated in Swift 4, so it's a good idea to explicitly mark Swift methods and properties callable from Swift with `@objc`.  In fact, you have to do it if `Swift 3 @objc inference` is set to `Off`.

Update: This needs to be further investigated, it may be just a matter of some settings.  I get the behavior you described if I add Swift code to a project initially set up as Objective-C, but internal members defined in Swift can be accessed just fine in Objective-C if the project is initially set up in Swift with Objective-C files added later.  Again, if Swift 3 @objc inference is disabled, you still have to mark such members with `@objc`.

Update 2: This access problem can be resolved in a project initially set up in Objective-C by adding a bridging header.  Then internal Swift members become visible in Objective-C, even though the purpose of a bridging header is the opposite: make Objective-C stuff visible in Swift.

Comment: I have another query about iOS 11. I have posted a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468044/storyboard-issue-in-xcode-9-text-overlapping-each-other ... Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Sorry, Sushil, I'm not sure what's going on there, I'm not much of a GUI expert. :(  But I do have an update to this question, see above.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Marking Swift variables @objc worked.